How does Soundpad route sound through your mic?
So I have been the most interested about the technology behind Soundpad. The biggest question I have and the one that I couldn't find an answer for is: How does Soundpad route the sound through your mic without you having to install any virtual audio cabels?
I tried to look this up, but I couldn't find a single answer to my problem.
